# Cannot turn on "Multi-Tenant" for Azure AD Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-billing-api

I've gone through several guides and spent several hours, but I can not seem to get Azure AD authentication working in my simple app.
I am trying to turn on "Application is multi-tenant" in my Azure Active Directory, and I get the following error:

> The App ID URI is not available. The App ID URI must be from a
>   verified domain within your organization's directory.

How can I change my Application to have the same domain as my Azure AD? (*.onmicrosoft.com).

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What is your App ID URI?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The message is pretty descriptive.

First you have to take a verified domain which is linked to your Azure AD. You can take it from the Domains tab on your Active Directory management page:

[image]

Then your AppID URI must be within any of those:

[image]

Only then you will be able to make your app Multi Tenant.

Comment: Hi, perhaps you know how to verify custom domain (that was bought from Azure) after I add it to my Azure Active Directory (I need it for multi-tenant mode for my API app)?

Comment: hi @Prokurors have you figured it out? I am facing the same issue - verify custom domain