# multi-tenant WebApp: no verified domain

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, multi-tenant, azure-active-directory

I have a node.js application which I deploy to an Azure WebApp. I have no custom domain, so I use *myapp.azurewebsites.net*.
I also created a AAD, called *mycompany.onmicrosoft.com*.
Here I registered my app with the App ID Uri *https://myapp.azurewebsites.net*.
Now I have a customer, which has it's own AAD. I want to grant my customer access to this app with his AAD.
So I tried to follow some tutorials, but I already failed trying to set "Multi-tenant" to "on", because I get this error: `The App ID URI is not available. The App ID URI must be from a verified domain within your organization's directory.`
So how can I turn on multi-tenancy for my app? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

As @BrunoMedina said, a verified domain is a requirement for a multi-tenant webapp.

You can refer to the doc [How to: Make my Azure web application multi tenant](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-PHP-Microsoft-Graph-Connect/wiki/How-to:-Make-my-Azure-web-application-multi-tenant) as explained to do it.

> The first one is self-explanatory, but whether you can enable the multi-tenant setting depends on the second one. To be able to make the application multi-tenant your App ID URI must be in a verified custom domain.

On Azure old portal, you can find the two key settings `Application is multi-tenant` & `App ID URI` below at the tab `CONFIGURE` of your application registed in your AAD domain.

Fig 1. The setting `Application is multi-tenant`
[image]

Fig 2. The setting `App ID URI`
[image]

Comment: Thank you, that explaines how to turn on Multi-tenancy. But the App ID Uri will be `something.onmicrosoft.com` while my app is hosted under `something.azurewebsites.net`. Will this work?

Comment: @Munchkin It's OK. Usually, we used `localhost` as `APP ID URI` in development.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a verified domain.

Please follow up to this question:

[Cannot turn on "Multi-Tenant" for Azure AD Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434176/cannot-turn-on-multi-tenant-for-azure-ad-authentication)